# Power Pi Pico by applying 5 V to VSYS—any experiences with or thoughts on additional safety measures?

Tags: power-supply, pi-pico, alternative-power

The official [Pico datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf) chapter 4.5 suggests using either a **Schottky diode** or a **P-channel MOSFET** (P-FET; or a combination of both) when powering the Pico from an external power source (at least if you want to keep the option of simultaneously connecting a computer via USB).

As a suitable P-MOSFET, they suggest Diodes DMG2305UX. However, I couldn't find this one in online stores here in Germany.

I wondered whether some of you have experiences with one or both of the options and could elaborate what good solutions are and which common diode/MOSFET models are the most suitable for the job (the job being in this case, to power the Pico).

From VSYS and the adjacent GND pin, I power an AirLift FeatherWing to provide the Pico with WLAN, as described in [this example](https://wikifactory.com/@finex/internet-on-a-pico). It needs up to 250 mA during Wifi use. Moreover, I want to connect 2 GY-BME280 using i2c and 2 DS18B20 on GPIO 16. These should use something of the magnitude of 1 mA per sensor, which, I guess, is negligible.

The power source will be [this 5 V 12 W power supply](https://amzn.eu/dXfPpx2) transforming 230 V 50 Hz AC to 5 V DC.

I attached two images from the original Pi Pico datasheet depicting both versions.

This is their version using the Schottky diode:

[image: Schottky diode version]

This is their version using the MOSFET:

[image: MOSFET version]

They added: "For inputs that have a low minimum input voltage, or if the P-
FET gate is expected to change slowly (e.g. if any capacitance is added to VBUS) a secondary Schottky diode across
the P-FET (in the same direction as the body diode) is recommended."

Comment: (1) For Pico with WiFi, I would suggest to use Pico W: (a) New Pi Pico W- WiFi Features, Specs & Pinout Simplified - etechnophiles
https://www.etechnophiles.com/raspberry-pi-pico-w-wifi-specs-pinout/

Comment: (2) Pico W's power cct is similar to Pico, so your question need lttle modification: https://imgur.com/a/vRC5e3U

Comment: (3) BME280 is a bit out of date. I would suggest to instead use BME680: (3.1) https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/gas-sensors/bme680//

(3.2) https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bme680-ds001.pdf

(3.3) https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/application_notes_1/bst-bme680-an014.pdf

(3.4) https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005004008302333.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2bra

Comment: (4) I surveyed Schottky diodes and found 1N5822 good (only 0.4V drop at 1A): https://imgur.com/a/8AVLt4O

Comment: (5) For P-MOSFET, I m thinking of trying this: IRF9540N datasheet - infineon
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535611cfa21dc8

Comment: (6) irf9540n summary: https://imgur.com/a/17nb9Fe.. IRF9540N vgs(th) max is 4V, so should be OK if Vgs = Vusb = 5V.

Comment: Now I have bought the BME280 and irf9540n. Next step is testing them: https://imgur.com/a/Qrbvxxu

Comment: (7) Now my first test is to use the P-channel power MOSFET IRF9540N as a high side switch to switch on/off power to RpiPico W. Reference: Low side vs High side switch - James Lewis, BaldEngineer
https://www.baldengineer.com/low-side-vs-high-side-transistor-switch.html

Comment: (8) IRF9540 P-channel power MOSFET as high side switch for external 5V power to RPi Pico W: https://imgur.com/a/aGDaNP4

Comment: (9) Next step is measuring IRF9540N Vgs(th) 5V and RsOn values: https://imgur.com/a/DCo6EUs

Comment: (10) IRF9540 switches Pico W 5V power: (a) https://imgur.com/a/RYaPRk8, 

(b) https://imgur.com/a/Fq6cZOn

Answer (score 3):

Although your question is call for sharing experience, I also have interpreted it as asking for help with realizing the circuits from datasheet. Since you cannot get the MOSFET referenced, you may want simply try alternatives that are on stock in Germany:

- [This one](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Micro-Commercial-Components-MCC/SI2301-TP?qs=SdqRYZZ9IxDQZSN6dfdoAA%3D%3D) has lower drain current (2.8 instead of 4.2), though with 12W supply it should be good enough. It also has insignificantly (i.e. 50mV) higher gate threshold voltage (450 mV instead of 400mV).
- [This one](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/DMP1045UQ-7?qs=W0yvOO0ixfG%252BpLf11SfNAw%3D%3D) has 100 mV lower threshold voltage should not matter neither, and lower drain-source breakdown (-12V instead of -20V), since you use it with 5V circuit, you won't ever exceed 12V, so should be fine too.
- Finally, [this](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/SI4403CDY-T1-GE3?qs=ROh%252BA47s9d1gMqbD3h1QGA%3D%3D) is very close to the original, with very high current rating (13.4 A). It has slightly less standard packaging, which may or may not matter to you.

There are a lot more alternatives at (e.g. Mouser) especially with leg-less SMD packaging.

*Note: I only checked catalog values which on rare occasions may not mach to the datasheets. It is a good idea to double-check datasheets before buying and using components*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the diode can only be there to prevent the Pico VSYS connecting to the external 5v rail in the event of the external psu failure whilst connected to USB input. As the pico can run with a supply to VSYS in the range of 1.8V to 5.5V, I would suggest that any diode would do as the slightly higher forward resistance of a non shottky diode would be very unlikely reduce 5v to less than 1.8V.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134181)